# How can I set a bounty?

Tags: support, bounty

I'd like to set a bounty to one of my questions, but I can't find a link for that. Is that because I have commented that question myself?

The question is [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/626109/).

Answer (score 3):

Your question is younger than two days, hence you cannot offer a bounty yet. See [mother meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/16067/263383) for more details on when bounties can be offered and awarded.